# MIDI track not changing pitch or instrument

Tags: java, audio, midi

I am fairly new to java programming and I'm trying to wrap my head around the javax.sound API (specifically midi sequencers) and am having trouble with some admittedly basic things. According to the documentation for the ShortMessage class one of the overloaded setmessage methods takes int command, int channel, int data1, int data2. I understand the first two arguments but I'm not totally sure what the options for the final two are. The book I'm trying to learn from say that it's the pitch and the velocity which make sense but when I change those ints neither the pitch or the volume of the note coming out of the speakers change at all. Here is my source code below.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class BeastBoxStarter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BeastBoxStarter playWithThis = new BeastBoxStarter();
        playWithThis.play();
    }

    public void play(){
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            try{
                Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
                Track track = seq.createTrack(); //initialize a track

                ShortMessage one = new ShortMessage(); //initialize a new ShortMessage
                one.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 127, 1); //set the message
                MidiEvent NoteOn = new MidiEvent(one, 1); //add a midi method to turn on the note
                track.add(NoteOn); //add the midi to the sequence track

                ShortMessage two = new ShortMessage(); //initialize a new ShortMessage
                one.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 1, 127, 1); //set the message
                MidiEvent NoteOff = new MidiEvent(two, 16); //add a midi method to turn on the note
                track.add(NoteOff); //add the midi to the track

                player.setSequence(seq); //add the sequence to the sequencer

                player.open();
                player.start(); //play the sequence with the sequencer
            }
            catch(InvalidMidiDataException iex){
                iex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (MidiUnavailableException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The `data1`/`data2` values are the data bytes of the MIDI messages (if it has them).

It is assumed that you know how MIDI messages are formatted.
See the [official specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification), or a [summary table](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-1-summary-of-midi-message).

For a Note On message, `data1` is the note number, and `data2` the velocity (= volume).
For a Note Off message, `data1` is the note number, and `data2` the velocity (which is usually ignored).

Comment: That was what I thought just wasn't sure where to find any documentation saying this. But my problem still stands: when I change data byte 1 the note pitch doesn't change at all

Comment: What exactly are you changing it to?

Comment: Any number between 0 and 127. It doesn't change pitch regardless of what number it changes to

Comment: Then you are probably not executing the changed code.

Comment: I have restarted my IDE, recompiled the code, tried to compile through the command line, and nothing changes the pitch. If you're saying I'm not recompiling the code between changing the numbers then that doesn't make any sense. If you're saying "then your code must be wrong" then yes I know that. That's why I am trying to get help to figure out what is wrong with it. I don't understand what you're saying and you sound like you just think I'm an idiot and it definitely doesn't make me want to keep programming, which I believe is the goal of stackoverflow.

Comment: It does not make sense that changing the note number has no effect. Anyway, try adding a second note with a different note number.

Comment: The sequencer was being opened at the wrong place. I don't think that the code would have worked on your machine. I suppose the reason you couldn't understand why the code wasn't working was because you never ran the code to see if it would work. You may want to do that in the future.